# Matrix comparing each element in vector1 to each element in vector2

Tags: r, vector, comparison

I want to compare each element in one vector (D) to each element in another vector (E) such that I get a matrix with dimensions length(D)xlength(E).

The comparison in question is of the form:

```
abs(D[i]-E[j])<0.1
```

So for

```
D <- c(1:5)
E <- c(2:6)
```

I want to get

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

(Or 1s and 0s to the same effect)

I have been able to get that output by doing something clunky like:

```
rbind(D%in%E[1],D%in%E[2],D%in%E[3],D%in%E[4],D%in%E[5])
```

and I could write a loop for 1:length(E), but surely there is a simple name and simple code for this operation? I have been struggling to find the language to search for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `outer` to perform the calculation in a vectorized manner across all pairs of elements in `D` and `E`:

```
outer(E, D, function(x, y) abs(x-y) <= 0.1)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I see two benefits over the sort of approach you've included in your question:

- It is less typing
- It is more efficient: the function is called just once with every single pair of `x` and `y` values, so it should be quicker than comparing `E[1]` against every element of `D`, then `E[2]`, and so on.

Comment: Aha!  And also `abs(sapply(D, "-", E)) < 0.1`

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah that is another good approach. I like `outer` a bit more in these situations because it does the whole calculation in a single vectorized call instead of n smaller calls (where n is the list of one of the vectors).

Answer (score 1):

Actually a direct approach would be (thanks to @alexis_laz):

```
n = length(E)
abs(E - matrix(D, ncol=n, nrow=n, byrow=T))<0.1

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: You could create only one of the matrices and rely on recycling, to avoid  creating many large objects. This can be an advantage over `outer` for this approach.

Comment: that's completely true and even quicker. I incorporated your comment